# Equivalent of apt-cacher-ng for CentOS

Tags: centos, cache, packages

What is the equivalent of [apt-cacher-ng](http://www.unix-ag.uni-kl.de/~bloch/acng/) for CentOS 6.3 64-bit? I did look around, but didn't find anything similar. I am installing some big packages on CentOS and want to store/share the packages later with others.

Answer (score 3):

Latest versions of apt-cacher-ng support CentOS.
As you can see from this Ubuntu bugreport they also fixed some minor issues when retrieving packages.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt-cacher-ng/+bug/1006844/comments/1